# Skyrim freezing while trying to enter Haemar's Shame

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

For the past hour I've been trying to enter Haemar's Shame so I could complete a Companions Request but it freezes everytime. I'm running Ps3 and have removed old save files. I don't have any idea what the deal is. I have about 120 hours logged and my save file is 13mb. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI - I've cleared this area once before, so this is something new. Which makes much more frustrating

Comment: While you might get an answer here, I'd recommend also asking on official game or support sites if you already haven't. Even if there is no official response, you're more likely to run into people who have also had the problem there (assuming others also saw it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game crashes in Haemar's Shrine if you've already completed "A Daedra's Best Friend".

Bethesda have announced [a fix for this issue in the Skyrim 1.4 patch](http://www.bethblog.com/2012/01/19/news-on-the-creation-kit-and-game-updates/).

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug caused by already clearing it earlier, probably when you did the "deadra's best friend quest" with the dog.